# Making bubble sort pure and efficient

Tags: javascript, sorting

### Background

I am re-writing a series of algorithms together with a colleague that we are going to later on publish in a packet for the community.

To start, I picked the typical bubble sort algorithm.

### Objectives

1. The function must be pure
2. It must be efficient
3. It must obey the complexities listed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Please note that by "being pure" it doesn't mean that it's inside code cannot have impurity. It merely means that the PUBLIC API of the function must be pure and it must not affect anything outside of its scope.

### Code

```
//PS: NOT really using lodash. Just copy pasted this one function xD
const isFunction = require("lodash.isfunction");
const defaultCompare = require("./defaultCompare");

const bubble = ( array, fnCompare = defaultCompare ) => {

    if( !isFunction(fnCompare) )
        throw new Error("fnCompare must be a function");

    if(!Array.isArray(array))
        throw new Error("array must be an Array");

    if (array.length === 0)
        return [];

    //shallow copy
    const clonedArray = array.slice();

    //Optimized bubble sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort
    let size = clonedArray.length;
    do{
        let newSize = 0;
        for( let i = 1; i < size; i++){
            if( fnCompare( clonedArray[i - 1], clonedArray[i] ) > 0 ){
                swap( clonedArray, i - 1, i );
                newSize = i;
            }
        }
        size = newSize;
    }while( size !== 0);

    return clonedArray;
};

const swap = (array, index1, index2) => {
    const temp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = temp;
};

module.exports = bubble;
```

### What do I want?

I am looking for any flaws in the code that could compromise objectives 1 and 3.

If you have an idea on how to improve object 2 (efficiency), I am all ears as well!

Comment: I wonder if you really need/want to clonedeep your array, as you will never modify your items anyway.  `const clonedArray = [...array];` seems enough ? You then let your user chose what to do with these items

Comment: also I think the swapping part would be more efficient if done this way : `[array[i], array[i + 1]] = [array[i + 1], array[i]];`

Comment: I am working now on following your cloning suggestion. I will also remove recursivity. Keep on with the ideas !

Comment: Not really pure when you throw to an unknown outside handler, if any, so basically terminating the execution of the calling context.

Comment: Also you can not call your code pure if any dependencies are not pure.

Comment: @Blindman67 would you care to elaborate on it a little bit better ?

Comment: @Blindman67 I kind of disagree with you on the fact that throwing makes a function non pure. Although I'm not (at all) an expert in fp, many people seem to argue that a function can be pure and raise exceptions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703232/why-is-the-raising-of-an-exception-a-side-effect

Comment: @Logar As I see it a single Javascript context  can never have a part of its self as  pure as it relies on trust rather than enforcement. Inherent in trust is behaviour regarding, ability to block, shares call stack, and memory,  no control over closure and associated scope. So the exceptions issue a mute point. Though using workers you can have enforced  purity and that includes no exceptions across contexts

Comment: New version of the algorithm, please let me know what you think !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given feedback I was able to remove the deepclone and to remove recursivity, which resulted in speed gains and simplicity gains.

The final version of the algorithm is now in the question ( I updated it ) and I will now mark this thread as solved.